# Sizing a capacitor for a large relay economizer

Tags: capacitor, relay

I am trying to figure out the correct size capacitor (and resistor, but that's easier) to make an economizer for a Kilovac EV200A1ANA relay.
The coil will burn up in minutes without any current limiting, so a resistor is added to limit the current to near the "holding current" amount. A larger current spike is needed to pull the relay closed, so a capacitor is often  used in parallel with the resistor to dump the needed current (3.8A for at most 130ms, in this case).

The relay coil specs are as follows (copied from the relay spec sheet):

- Coil voltage: 9-36 V
- Hold voltage (min.): 7.5 V
- Inrush current (max.): 3.8 A
- Holding current (avg.): 0.13 A@12 V
- Inrush time (max.): 130 ms

I will be using this on a 12 V (4S LiFePO4 battery) circuit.

To calculate the capacitor's value, I used **3.8 A x 13 V = 49.4 W**
To get Joules, I took **50 W x 0.13 s = 10 Joules**
To get farads, I took **10 J / (13 V<sup>2</sup> x 0.5) = 0.118 F**
In µF, that's **118000 µF**. The largest µF capacitor I could find on McMaster Carr was 2000 µF.

Do I really need to solder nearly 60 of these in parallel, or is there something off in my math? I know this is elementary stuff, but that seems like a really large result, and need a sanity check.

Comment: You might want to tell what is a relay economizer to understand what it should do and why you think those values that you used should be used for calculations.

Comment: McMaster isn't really a good source for electrical components, to my knowledge. Try Digikey or Mouser. 118 mF is pretty big, but you can get them. The problem, though, is that your calculations are wrong. The capacitor doesn't need to store 10 J.

Comment: @Hearth That's a relief. I thought 118 mF seemed pretty high. Can you show me where I went wrong?

Comment: @Acercanto The 10 J you calculated is the energy (actually, the max energy, it probably doesn't actually need nearly that much) the relay consumes in order to switch. That has nothing to do with the capacitance required; the capacitor doesn't need to store that energy, the *relay* needs to use it. Though this *is* quite a slow-switching relay--it might be better to use a different type of economizer instead. Something with a timer and a switch to switch the resistor in after a set time.

Comment: Here is an article that deals with relay economizers. One take away is that in the simple circuit the resistor limiting the current will still dissipate a good amount of power making the savings minimal. Other designs using PWM increase efficiency and some examples are given:  https://www.electronicdesign.com/power-management/article/21805068/reap-the-benefits-of-economizers-for-solenoidrelay-drivers

Comment: According to the [datasheet](https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-1618002-1.datasheet.pdf) the coil is 3.14 ohms. How is the holding current only 0.13 A @ 12 V?

Comment: I think whoever did that datasheet used the inrush current of 3.8A at 12V to (wrongly) calculate 3.14 ohms. One easy way to estimate the size of an economizer capacitor is to use the RC time constant of 118 ms and the coil resistance 12/0.13 = 92 ohms. So 118/92 = 1.28 mF or about 1300 uF which is easily available. It might require more, especially for 12V, so I'd try 3300 or 4700 uF.

Answer (score 1):

Set that contactor aside. Buy a Kilovac EV200 contactor with a built-in economizer ([also from TE](https://www.rec-bms.com/datasheet/Technical_datasheet_Kilovac.pdf)). Or buy a dual coil contactor ([from GigaVac](https://www.waytekwire.com/item/77100/GIGAVAC-GV241MAX-Sealed-Dual-Coil-Contactor-/)).

Comment: I actually have another (EV200AAANA)  with the economizer built in, but it pulls a lot more than the spec sheet says is the min holding current, so I wanted to make one that would be a little more battery friendly.

Comment: In that case, forget about Kilovac contactors: they use a lot of power. Look at Gigavac instead. Also, consider latching contactors, though be aware that they are not failsafe, so they may not be acceptable in your application.